# Mysql Ranking with Group_Concat and SUM

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Thank you for everyone that has been asnwer the question.

I have found the solution with group_concat. The query:

```
SELECT nisn,sum(nilai_angka) 

( select find_in_set( sum(nilai_angka),
( select
group_concat(distinct sum(nilai_angka)
order by sum(nilai_angka) DESC separator ',')
from nilai))
) as rangking

FROM nilai  
 group by nisn
```

But  i got problem because find_in_set and group_concat can't receive SUM.

Any idea?

Comment: Keep in mind that the mysql_* extension is seriously deprecated and you should remove it as soon as possible.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.  Stack Overflow questions should not require on external sites for their content.

Comment: thankyou :). i've provide data sample. hope it can help you

Comment: hi all. i've edit the questions and make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, i can really understand the names of fields in database, but here's a snipplet from one of the tasks from my last job interview which is pretty simmilar to what you're asking.

```
SELECT
CONCAT(pF," ",pI," ",pO) AS pupil, 
#concat last,first and middle name of the student

@curRank := IF(@prevVal=score, @curRank, @curRank:= @curRank + 1 ) AS rank,
#compare scores to previous student to split places in case of equal results

@prevVal:=score as score
#save current score to compare with next student

FROM 
(SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevVal:=null) r, 
#trick to init variables without second query
tbl_results
#Fields: puppil_id, subject_id, score

LEFT JOIN tbl_pupils ON tbl_results.pupil_id=tbl_pupils.pidx
#Fields: pidx, pF, pI, pO

WHERE subject_id=2
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

The trick here is that `SELECT @curRank:=` gets calculated after `ORDER BY` statement, which makes it very easy.
Here is a interactive version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fee20/15
But it seems to be down at this moment.

Comment: again, im not sure what is the problem, but i see that `sum(nilai_angka)` got repeated three times, which doesnt sound right. Try changing it to `group_concat(distinct sum(nilai_angka) AS nilai_sum` and then change others to `nilai_sum` instead.